# Why is MySQL choosing that index, and how slow is too slow?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, amazon-rds

I have a large indexed table with over 35 million rows. Here are the indexes, with a naming convention that shows their sequential column order:

```
IDX_E93438363DAE128B,
IDX_LIST_ID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_DELETED,
IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_FIRST_NAME,
IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_LAST_UPDATED_AT
```

My query of this table on my medium Amazon RDS instance is taking upwards of 15 minutes:

```
SELECT * FROM contact
WHERE list_id = '014c7cba-c124-11e5-b4ea-0a4287b2e8c5'
AND subscribed = 1
AND deleted = 0
```

Using an `EXPLAIN` of the query I can see that MySQL is choosing to use the `IDX_LIST_ID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_DELETED` key, when I'd expect most of the other keys (`IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_...`) to be more optimal.

Should I just trust the engine? Is 17 or so minutes a realistic time to wait for a query on a table this large?

Comment: Do you need to be using `SELECT *`? By doing so, you are forcing the database to go back to the primary key row for each and every row it finds with its index. Also, what engine? MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've refined my query to just `SELECT id, email_address, first_name, last_name FROM...`, but I still get the same issue. I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: What's the performance when you do `select * from contact use index (idx_list_id_subscribed_deleted_first_name) where ...`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, email_address, first_name, last_name 
FROM contact
WHERE list_id = '014c7cba-c124-11e5-b4ea-0a4287b2e8c5'
AND subscribed = 1
AND deleted = 0
```

Given the above query, the best index will be

```
ALTER TABLE `contact`
CREATE INDEX (`list_id`,`subscribed`,`deleted`,`email_address`,`first_name`,`last_name`)
```

That will allow it to look up all necessary rows with the leftmost 3 fields, and all remaining values are present to the right of that. This assumes that `id` is the primary key of your table, else you'll have to add that to the right of `deleted` in that index.

This should maximize the the speed at which you can run this query, at least as far as just changing indexes goes.

If, with this index, you are still having problems, please let us know what the result of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM contact
WHERE list_id = '014c7cba-c124-11e5-b4ea-0a4287b2e8c5'
AND subscribed = 1
AND deleted = 0
```

returns. You simply may have that a huge number of rows, which can take time to return.